# Highchart is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I used following file to display a highchart. but it doesnt display anything at all. Can anyone point me the mistake here. I just used code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/SykAf/)
Is the ordering of javascript import correct.? could anyone please help me to correct this html to display highchart.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'ohlc',
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {

                            var x = (new Date()).getTime();

                            series.addPoint([
                            x,
                            Math.random()*100,
                            Math.random()*100,
                            Math.random()*100,
                            Math.random()*100
                            ], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'}]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                type: 'ohlc',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push([
                            time + i * 1000,
                            Math.random()*100,
                            Math.random()*100,
                            Math.random()*100,
                            Math.random()*100
                            ]);
                    }
                    return data;
                })()}]
        });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should check your console. I get http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17 - *"The requested series type does not exist"*. Changing the series type to *"line"* yields this ~ http://jsfiddle.net/7utv77xy/1/

Comment: but in here it works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/SykAf/

Comment: @Chann Your example doesn't include the highcharts.js file. I guess you don't need it. Here's the working version ~ http://jsfiddle.net/7utv77xy/2/

Comment: it works fine in jsfiddle, but when i run the html file in browser it doesn't display the graph

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript console is saying undefined function. When I put the highstock script above the exporting script, as in the jsfiddle you linked, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you refer to serie OHLC which is supported only in Highstock. So you need to attach highstock.js